# How to generate log file in the project root folder?

Tags: quarkus

I have a small learning Quarkus Project. My logging configuration

```
# Configure Logging to File.
quarkus.log.file.enable=true
quarkus.log.file.path=quarkus.log
quarkus.log.file.level=INFO
quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-file-size=10M
quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-backup-index=5
quarkus.log.file.rotation.file-suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
quarkus.log.file.rotation.rotate-on-boot=true
```

I do logging with

```
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(AppLifecycleService.class);
```

My expectation was that the quarkus.log file would be created in the root folder of the project. But it doesn't. How should the configuration be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is correct, with the same settings in a test repo, Quarkus creates the log file in the root, as you expect it.

Possibly there's some issue in the background, missing permissions maybe?
I'd suggest starting Quarkus in dev mode with executing `quarkus dev` or `mvn quarkus:dev` and setting the console logging to debug level, by pressing `J` key, as it's described in the interactive mode's help section.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced this problem too. Setup: Quarkus 3.5.3, Dev mode, Kotlin, Windows

For my case, the problem was that the logs went to build\classes\kotlin\main\

I solved it by changing the working directory (in dev mode) to project root directory, by adding this in build.gradle.kts:

```
tasks.quarkusDev {
    workingDirectory = rootProject.projectDir
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I utilise the `logs` directory to keep the project directory clean.

```
quarkus.log.file.enable=true
%dev.quarkus.log.file.path=logs/quarkus-dev.log
quarkus.log.file.path=shared/logs/quarkus.log
```

However, it is impossible to say what is wrong with your case. You haven't done all that substantial to assist you.

If logging is enabled, Quarkus should also log some of its own outputs. Try the following settings:

```
quarkus.log.file.level=ALL
```

It would also be wonderful if you could publish your solution if you solved your problem. It is not fair to the community if people post queries and then stop caring about them.